# FTP using sublime text 2 for Mac

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way to open files on a ftp using Sublime Text 2 for a Mac, or is there a tutorial somewhere that explains how to do it?

I have been looking around and can't find anything

Answer (score 1):

There's a great package that adds SFTP and FTP capabilities to Sublime. Check out [Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp). Has a free trial available, but it's well worth the $16 license.